# "templating" a namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I'd like to build something like this:

```
File 1:
template<typename Vector>
namespace myNamespace {
  class myClass1{ myClass1(Vector v) {...} }
}

File 2:
template<typename Vector>
namespace myNamespace {
  class myClass2{ myClass2(Vector v) {...} }
}
```

Of course this is not possible because you cannot template namespaces.
Instead I could use a struct instead of a namespace, but then I cannot spread the namespace functions over several files.

Is there any solution for such a problem?

PS: I know I could template the classes, but then I'd have to specify which vector type I want to use anytime I create a new class.

Comment: Concerning your PS: How do you think having a templated namespace would remove the need to specify the type of vector when you instantiate classes? You'd still need at least something like a (fictional) `using namespace myNamespace<some_vector_t>;`

Comment: I'm with stakx on this. And what's that `int` in your code?

Comment: Yes, but then you could do something like this:

    int function1() {
      using namespace myNamespace<int>;
      myClass1 c1 = myClass1(5);
      myClass2 c2 = myClass2(2);
    }
    int function2() {
      using namespace myNamespace<char>;
      myClass1 c1 = myClass1('a');
      myClass2 c2 = myClass2('b');
    }


Sorry, that int is wrong, I'll delete it.
How do I paste code here correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on your comment:

Instead of writing

`using namespace myNamespace<int>;`

Just use templated classes and write this instead (or whatever variation):

```
typedef myNamespace::myClass1<int> myClass1Int;
typedef myNamespace::myClass2<int> myClass2Int;
```

I tend to think it's better to be explicit about what types are being used rather than trying to do something like import a particular instantiation of a namespace.

Can you more fully describe the problem that makes you think templated namespaces would be useful?

And remember you can always write a `make_myClass1` free function to deduce the template type for you.

Comment: @Mark B I know this is a really old question, but what if you want something like a `Util` class with only static methods? Wouldn't using a namespace be better for that?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that, but you can provide different namespaces and typedefs (not that I endorse it).

```
namespace template_impl {
   template <typename V>
   class myClass1_tmpl {...};
   template <typename V>
   class myClass2_tmpl {...};
}
namespace myns_Vector1 {
   typedef ::template_impl::myClass1_tmpl<Vector1> myClass1;
   typedef ::template_impl::myClass2_tmpl<Vector1> myClass2;
}
void foo() {
   using namespace myns_Vector1;
   myClass1 mc1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, my classes have several template parameters.
Now I created this approach:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace myNamespace {
  template<typename _integer, typename _string>
  struct s {
    typedef _integer integer;
    typedef _string string;
  };

  template<class T>
  class classA {
  public:
    static typename T::integer intFunc() { return 1; }
    static typename T::string stringFunc() { return "hallo"; }
  };
}


int main() {
  using namespace myNamespace;

  typedef s<int, std::string> types1;
  typedef s<unsigned int, char*> types2;

  std::cout << classA<types1>::intFunc() << std::endl;
  std::cout << classA<types1>::stringFunc() << std::endl;

  std::cout << classA<types2>::intFunc() << std::endl;
  std::cout << classA<types2>::stringFunc() << std::endl;

}
```

and I think I'll combine it with Mark B's approach!

Cheers, guys!

Answer (score 0):

... and in the year 2023

```
namespace ns::nested_ns
{
   template<typename T, typename T2>
   class example_class
   {
      ...
      ...
   };
} 

using ec = ns::nested_ns::example_class<int, float>;
```