# Why can't namespaces be templated?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, standards

I'm working on a library which has several template classes, all interrelated to such an extent that they all have the same template parameters. In a sense, a given template parameter set describes an nearly-self-contained universe of classes, maybe with a one or two routes between these class universes.

In current C++, I have no real way of grouping such 'class universes' together, except in a rather ugly and manual way. Here's an example of some inter-related templated classes that might highlight my point:

```
template<size_t dimension>
using vector_t = std::array<double, dimension>;

template<typename weight_t, size_t outer_dimension, size_t inner_dimension>
class A{
protected:
    weight_t weight;
public:
    weight_t get_weight(
        const vector_t<outer_dimension>& foo,
        const vector_t<inner_dimension>& bar
    ) const;
};

template<typename weight_t, size_t outer_dimension, size_t inner_dimension>
class B{
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A<weight_t, outer_dimension, inner_dimension>>> A_vector;
};

template<typename weight_t, size_t outer_dimension, size_t inner_dimension>
class C{
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A<weight_t, outer_dimension, inner_dimension>>> A_vector;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B<weight_t, outer_dimension, inner_dimension>>> B_vector;
public:
    typename std::enable_if<
        (inner_dimension > 0),
        C<weight_t, outer_dimension + 1, inner_dimension - 1>
    >::type do_something() const;
};
```

This is usable - and, in the actual library I'm working on, the structure is ideal for what I want to use it for. It is, on the other hand, extremely ugly, and rather explicit for my liking.

If templated namespaces existed in the C++ standard, I could do something a little nicer:

```
template<size_t dimension>
using vector_t = std::array<double, dimension>;

template<typename weight_t, size_t outer_dimension, size_t inner_dimension>
namespace universe{
    typedef vector_t<outer_dimension> outer_vector;
    typedef vector_t<inner_dimension> inner_vector;

    class A{
    protected:
        weight_t weight;
    public:
        weight_t get_weight(const outer_vector& foo, const inner_vector& bar) const;
    };

    class B{
    protected:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> A_vector;
    };

    class C{
    protected:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> A_vector;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> B_vector;
    public:
        typename std::enable_if<
            (inner_dimension > 0),
            universe<weight_t, outer_dimension + 1, inner_dimension - 1>::C
        >::type do_something() const;
    };
}
```

Of course, templated namespaces *don't* exist in the C++ standard. There are some really hacky approaches to get around this, e.g. ["templating" a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319503/templating-a-namespace). Solutions include:

- using typedefs to make the whole point of templating redundant
- wrapping typedefs in namespaces to make the point of redundant
  templating even *more* redundant.
- having a 'types' struct, which is more preferable than the above two but still ugly (IMO).

Obviously, such solutions are workarounds to the fundamental issue - that namespaces can't be templated. Is there a specific reason that this has not been adopted by the standard, or is it simply something that is yet to be proposed (in an effective manner)?

I can see a variety of other use cases - for example, there are many generic libraries out there with a lot of focus on a single typedef template parameter, which could benefit from one overall parameter.

Comment: Asking why a feature doesn't exist is more likely to attract opinion-based answers than objective ones, unless said feature was proposed and rejected (I don't believe that's the case). Feel free to [submit a proposal](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal) to the standardizing committee.

Comment: The fact that templated namespace are useful is indeed opinion-dependent, but OP's question is really factual: _"Is there a specific reason that this has not been adopted by the standard, or is it simply something that is yet to be proposed (in an effective manner)?"_

Comment: ... but it's really unprobable one could find a rationale explaining _why_ something does not exist.

Comment: I understand this, and I was quite apprehensive about asking the question in this manner. In fact, my aim *is* to submit a proposal (it would be my first proposal) - but first I want to ensure that (A) it has not been proposed before (although I couldn't find evidence of that), (B) I see any concerns people may have, so that I can refine the idea and make a stronger proposal, and (C) if any people working on the compiler side could see this being more complex to actually implement than I am aware of.

Comment: @JArkinstall The appropriate place for discussing all the points you mentioned is the ISO C++ mailing list, not SO.

Comment: "but still ugly" Where? What unspeakable things will happen if you replace the word `namespace` with the word `struct` in your second listing?

Comment: @n.m. Nothing unspeakable will happen, but it is clearly a hacky approach. By ugly I don't mean 'overcomplicated', I mean that it is not pretty. The method I'm referring to isn't, by the way, replacing 'namespace' with 'struct' - it is passing a wrapper object as a template parameter. Unless I'm wrong here, this has some implications w.r.t. SFINAE and non-typename template parameters.

tambre - I am doing so now. I will close this thread if that is appropriate.

Comment: "The method I'm referring to isn't" But the method **I**'m referring to **is**. It works exactly like a namespace would, because a class is a namespace for purposes of name lookup.

Comment: [class namespace](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0223r0.html) seems a nearly identical proposal. I guess it didn't  make it through because of the disproportion between the alleged benefits and the enormous effort of getting it right ...

Comment: @n.m. You are correct, I ignored your comment's merits as a suggestion in order to focus on the part being quoted. Sorry about that. I do agree with you to an extent - where we part, I guess, is in semantics. If we need a struct in order to achieve a job that namespaces are designed to do in the first place, then there is room for improvement IMO.