# Structured template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Building on top of this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319851/13250135

I'd like to structure my template parameters into schemes, because the same classes are used in different contexts in the same application.

```
// adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319851
template<typename _string, typename _real>
struct scheme{
    public:
    using string = _string;
    using real = _real;
};

using scheme1 = scheme<std::string_view, double>;
using scheme2 = scheme<std::string, float>;

template<class scheme>
class Test {
    scheme::string text;
    scheme::real value;
    std::array<int, 10> array{};
};

Test<scheme1> test1{};
Test<scheme2> test2{};
```

So far so good. But now I need a type that is parametric in itself. For instance, I'd like to equally parametrize the `std::array<T>` with potential alternatives.

EDIT: to add more info.

I'd like to achieve something like that:

```
template<typename _string, typename _real, typename _collection>
struct scheme{
    public:
    using string = _string;
    using real = _real;
    using collection = _collection;
};

using scheme1 = scheme<std::string_view, double, std::array>;
using scheme2 = scheme<std::string, float, myNamespace::myArray>;

template<class scheme>
class Test {
    scheme::string text;
    scheme::real value;
    scheme::collection<int, 10> array{};
};
```

But of course this does not work, as `std::array` without parameters is not a valid typename. But I need to be able to provide these final parameters only where the template is instantiated, e.g. in the `Test` class.

Why would I want such a thing?

Some classes are to be used both in a `constexpr` scheme (all const data, obviously), but also in various non-const schemes. For instance, I could use `std::string_view`, for the `constexpr` scheme and `std::string` for the non-const scheme.

Another example could be to provide compatibility with data that is persisted in version specific binary data schemes (migrating data from 32bit to 64bit, code page to Unicode etc.). Newer versions of the application would need to implement all the schemes to be able to read the old data after upgrading.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: It's not clear to me what programming problem you are trying to solve. You may want to [edit] your post and add more details.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You can add additional template parameters, so you can add parameters to `Test`, specifically for the `std::array`.

Comment: Your `scheme` might have types for `int` or `std::array<int, 10>`, `constexpr size_t` for `10`, or even a `template using` taking `int, 10` in place of `std::array`.

Comment: How and where do you need to parameterize? It is that the class `Test` need many kind of list that may be many kind of `std::array` of the same size? Why does the current pattern not working? I want to help but I have a hard time understanding what you actually need.

Comment: `template template` parameter comes to mind, but it not enough information is given to fully understand if it is what you need.

Comment: I have edited the question to be clearer, I hope. @Jarod42, the int and 10 are "parameters to the parameters" i.e. they should remain variable inside the scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `_collection` a template template parameter.

```
template<typename _string, typename _real, template<typename, size_t> typename _collection>
struct scheme{
    public:
    using string = _string;
    using real = _real;
    // This is now a template type alias, i.e. "variable inside the scheme"
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    using collection = _collection<T, N>;
};
```

Your `Test` class would look as follows:

```
template<class scheme>
class Test {
    scheme::string text;
    scheme::real value;
    // As collection is no longer a type, the additional template disambiguator is needed here...
    scheme::template collection<int, 10> array{};
};
```

Notice that this solution will only work for templates with the same "signature" as `std::array` namely one type parameter followed by one integral non-type parameter. `std::vector` for example will not work.
For this reason, depending on the actual type of `myNamespace::myArray` this solution might not be viable for your problem.

Edit: I realised you added the c++20 tag to your question. In this case you can omit the three `typename`s in the `Test` class.
Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/h3P8qn).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great. Can you recommend a book about such things? Covering C++20?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've learned it the painful way by trial and error.